# [matlab-prettifier]: Package Listings Error: Couldn't Load Requested Style

Tags: matlab-prettifier

I am using matlab-prettifier to write matlab codes inside my LaTeX files. The block codes work fine, but the inline codes gives the error **Package Listings Error: Couldn't Load Requested Style**. How can I fix this error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\begin{document}
% This is not working
This is an inline code \lstinline[style=Matlab-style]!break!

% This is working
\begin{lstlisting}
i = 1;
for i < 10
    i = i + 1;
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From where do you have that there is a style called `Matlab-style`?

Comment: Set a language as `Matlab`. The list of all languages and names is in the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) p. 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matlab-prettifier [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/matlab-prettifier/matlab-prettifier.pdf) mentions the available styles in the section 4 "Styles provided by matlab-prettifier" on page 6:

> The package defines three listings styles for Matlab code: `Matlab-editor`,
> `Matlab-bw`, and `Matlab-Pyglike`. Those styles differ in terms of color scheme
>
> [...]
>
> Here is a comparison of the three styles defined by `matlab-prettifier`.
>
> **Matlab-editor** This style mimics the default style of the Matlab editor.
>
> **Matlab-bw** This style is mainly for black & white printing.
>
> **Matlab-Pyglike** The minted, verbments, and pythontex packages all use Pygments lexers for syntax highlighting of listings. This matlab-prettifier style closely mimics the default style associated with Pygments’ `MatlabLexer`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\begin{document}
% This is not working
This is an inline code \lstinline[style=Matlab-editor]!break!

% This is working
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-pyglike]
i = 1;
for i < 10
    i = i + 1;
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]